# full screen on big screen computer, the width over max-width, gray background happen

Tags: android, jquery, html, css

Look at my image below, #myshop div max-width is 1200px, when I using a very screen computer, it looks below. How can I fix this, the only thing I cannot change is that I cannot change the max-width of the #myshop, so how can I make it looks fine in a large screen computer. In small computer, laptop is OK. Apprciate.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--><html <?php language_attributes(); ?>> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
 <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
 
 <title><?php wp_title('|', true, 'right'); ?></title>
 
 <?php wp_head(); ?>
 
 
 <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="<?php echo THEMEASSETS; ?>js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
 <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
 
 <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->

 <div id="top_head">
  <a href="http://sayhitoworld.spreadshirt.com/shop/help/index/" id="top_help">Help?</a>
  <div id="checkout_top" class="spreadplugin-checkout"><a target="_self">Shopping bag</a>(<span></span>)</div>
<a id="track_order" href="https://sayhitoworld.spreadshirt.com/shop/logon">Track Order</a>
</div><!--top_head-->
 
 
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
  
 <?php if(function_exists('WC')): ?>
  <?php get_template_part('tpls/header-cart'); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 
 <?php if( ! defined("NO_HEADER_MENU")): ?>
 <div class="wrapper">
  
  <?php
  
  define("HAS_SLIDER", in_array('revslider/revslider.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins'))) && function_exists("register_field_group") && ($revslider_id = get_field('revslider_id')));
  
  # Menu
  if(HEADER_TYPE == 1)
  {
   get_sidebar('menu'); 
  }
  else
  if(in_array(HEADER_TYPE, array(2,3,4)))
  {
   get_sidebar('menu-top');
   
   # Slider
   if(HAS_SLIDER)
   {
    if(is_search())
     echo "<div style='height: 30px;'></div>";
    else
     echo putRevSlider($revslider_id);
   }
  }
  ?>
  
  <div class="main<?php echo HEADER_TYPE == 1 && HAS_SLIDER ? ' hide-breadcrumb' : ''; ?>">
  
   <?php get_template_part('tpls/breadcrumb'); ?>
   
   <?php 
   # Slider
   if(HEADER_TYPE == 1 && HAS_SLIDER):

    ?>    
    <div class="rev-slider-container row">
     <?php echo putRevSlider($revslider_id); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    
   endif;
   ?>
 
 <?php endif; ?>
```

[image]

```html
<div class="page-container">

 <?php if($is_vc_page === false): ?>
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="white-block block-pad">
    <h1 class="single-page-title"><?php echo the_title(); ?></h1>
    
    <div class="post-content">
     <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 <?php else: ?>
  <?php the_content(); ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
 
  <div id="myshop_wrap">
  <div id='top_basket'></div>
  <div id="myshop"></div>
 </div>
 

  <script>
      var spread_shop_config= {
          "shopName" : "hitoworld",
          "locale" : "us_US",
          "prefix" : "//shop.spreadshirt.com",
          "baseId" : "myshop"
   };
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//shop.spreadshirt.com/shopfiles/shopclient/shopclient.nocache.js"></script>
 
 
</div><!--page-container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

create another media query and set a min-width of 1201px

inside the query and some spacing on either side (left/right)in percentages of your container. But without your code I cannot give you an example. I will update with example if you share your code.

Comment: Thanks for you response, I just add the code, #myshop is the cause, because I cannot change the max-width of the #myshop.Appreciate

Comment: Now that I see a bit of your code, it appears that you are using bootstrap, right? If so, you have a totally different issue.

Comment: yes, It is the theme, I use oxygen theme, but I change the theme. If it is not using bootstrap, how can I fixed that? or if it is using bootstrap, how can I do that too?

Comment: the `<div class="col-md-12">` part of your html says at one point you were using bootstrap. In your head do you have any references to bootstrap.min.css or bootstrap.js?

Comment: I just upload the header template, I don't see any references to bootstrp.min.css, I am using wordpress. This theme force me to use WPBakery Visual Composer. I guess WPBakery Visual Composer use bootstrap